# How does slf4j bind to the Logging Framework

Tags: logging, slf4j

I was going through the [slf4j code](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j) to understand the binding process when I stumbled upon the [`bind()`](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/blob/master/slf4j-api/src/main/java/org/slf4j/LoggerFactory.java#L140) method in the [`LoggerFactory`](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/blob/master/slf4j-api/src/main/java/org/slf4j/LoggerFactory.java) class

Code snippet of lines of interest:

```
        if (!isAndroid()) {
            staticLoggerBinderPathSet = findPossibleStaticLoggerBinderPathSet();
            reportMultipleBindingAmbiguity(staticLoggerBinderPathSet);
        }
        // the next line does the binding
        StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton();
        INITIALIZATION_STATE = SUCCESSFUL_INITIALIZATION;
        reportActualBinding(staticLoggerBinderPathSet);
        replayEvents();
```

The method [`findPossibleStaticLoggerBinderPathSet()`](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/blob/master/slf4j-api/src/main/java/org/slf4j/LoggerFactory.java#L292) is something like this:

```
private static String STATIC_LOGGER_BINDER_PATH = "org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class";
try {
        ClassLoader loggerFactoryClassLoader = LoggerFactory.class.getClassLoader();
        Enumeration<URL> paths;
        if (loggerFactoryClassLoader == null) {
            paths = ClassLoader.getSystemResources(STATIC_LOGGER_BINDER_PATH);
        } else {
            paths = loggerFactoryClassLoader.getResources(STATIC_LOGGER_BINDER_PATH);
        }
```

Since the default [`slf4j-api`](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/blob/master/slf4j-api/) package provides a class with name [`StaticLoggerBinder`](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/blob/master/slf4j-api/src/main/java/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.java) with some defaults and depends on the actual implementations provided by the Binding Projects ([log4j](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/blob/master/slf4j-log4j12/src/main/java/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.java), logback etc.).

How does it actually identify which `StaticLoggerBinder` class to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, StaticLoggerBinder is in the source of `slf4j-api`, but it is removed so it does not end up in the jar. If you download the JAR, you will see it is not there.